# How to write out a byte-array variable from this pseudo code in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I need to set array to empty array of bytes then get the length of password and append it to passwordarray

`**SET PasswordArray TO (empty array of bytes) SET PasswordArray[0] TO Password.Length APPEND Password TO PasswordArray**`

I wrote this and it doesnt seem like I am getting anything when I print it out

```
password_array = bytearray([])
   password_array[0] = len(str(password)).append(str(password_array))
   print(password_array)
```

The full function is right here just in case

```
#!/bin/python3
import os
import sys

import numpy

import office2john

def password_verifier(password):
    password = int(input())

    verifier = [numpy.uint16(1)] 
    password_array = [numpy.uint8(1)]
    verifier = 0x0000

    password_array = bytearray([])
    password_array[0] = len(str(password)).append(str(password_array))         
    print(password_array)

    for byte in password_array:
        intermediate1 = 0 
        if verifier and 0x4000 == 0x0000:
            intermediate1 = 0
        elif byte == 0x0000:
            intermediate1 = 1
        else: 
            intermediate2 = verifier * 2
            intermediate2 = 0
            intermediate3 = intermediate1 ^ intermediate2
            verifier = intermediate3 ^ 0xCE4B
            break
        print(byte)
        return verifier ^ 0xCE4B


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #password = os.system("python3 office2john.py easypasswd.xlsx")
    print(password_verifier)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want an array of bytes where the first byte is the length of the password. Something like this:

```
p = 'abc123'
b = bytearray()
b.append(len(p))
b.extend([ord(c) for c in p])
print(b)
```

This will output `b'\x06abc123'`